# How to create a big number of threads in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I found a [topic](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/racket-users/NX1quS7vaVE/d-y8Y6xwsz0J) in the Racket group about the performance of `channel` creating.

I want to write a OCaml's version to test.

```
let post (c,x) = Event.sync (Event.send c x);;

let accept c = Event.sync (Event.receive c);;

let get_chan c = let n = accept c in print_int n;print_newline ();;

let chan_trans (old_chan, new_chan) =
  let s = accept old_chan in
  post (new_chan,(s+1));;

let rec whisper count init_val =
  let rec aux n chan =
    if n >= count then chan
    else
      let new_chan = Event.new_channel ()
      in Thread.create chan_trans (chan, new_chan);
      aux (n+1) new_chan
  in let leftest_chan = Event.new_channel ()
  in let t0 = Thread.create post (leftest_chan, init_val)
  in let rightest_chan = aux 0 leftest_chan
  in get_chan rightest_chan;;

whisper 10000 1;;
```

The question is, when I tested for `whisper 1000 1`, it produced `1001` as expected. However, when I tried to test `whisper 10000 1`, there's an error as

> Fatal error: exception Sys_error("Thread.create: Resource temporarily unavailable")

I used this command to compile and run

> ocamlc -thread unix.cma threads.cma -o prog whisper.ml&&./prog -I
>   +threads

Comment: Maybe you want to use lwt http://ocsigen.org/lwt/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OCaml Thread module uses the real system (kernel) threads. The total number of threads is bounded by the kernel:

```
 cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
 251422
```

You can increase this of course,

```
 echo 100000 > /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
```

but a better approach would be to treat threads as a resource and manage them correspondingly.

```
let rec whisper count init_val =
  let rec aux n t chan =
    if n >= count then chan
    else
      let new_chan = Event.new_channel () in
      let t' = Thread.create chan_trans (chan, new_chan) in
      Thread.join t;
      aux (n+1) t' new_chan in
  let leftest_chan = Event.new_channel () in
  let t = Thread.create post (leftest_chan, init_val) in
  let rightest_chan = aux 0 t leftest_chan in
  get_chan rightest_chan
```

In that case it will run with any size of the pipeline. For example:

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -tag thread -pkg threads ev.native
$ time ./ev.native 
100001

real    0m1.581s
```

But this implementation of Chinese Whispers is very crude and inefficient. You shouldn't use heavyweight native threads for this (and neither go uses them). Instead, you should use cooperative lightweight threads from [Lwt](http://ocsigen.org/lwt/) or [Async](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/concurrent-programming-with-async.html) libraries. This would be much efficient and nice.

## Implementation with Lwt

This implementation follows closely the Go implementation from the [blog post](https://cxwangyi.wordpress.com/2012/07/29/chinese-whispers-in-racket-and-go/), but I think that we can do this more efficient and concise in OCaml without using mailboxes (but I'm not sure whether it will conform to the rules of the benchmark).

```
open Lwt.Infix

let whispers n =
  let rec whisper i p =
    if i < n then
      Lwt_mvar.take p >>= fun x ->
      whisper (i+1) (Lwt_mvar.create (x+1))
    else Lwt_mvar.take p in
  whisper 0 (Lwt_mvar.create 1)

let () = print_int @@ Lwt_main.run (whispers 100000)
```

The results are:

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -tag thread -pkg lwt.unix lev.native --
$ time ./lev.native 
100001
real    0m0.007s
```

To compare with Go implementation on mine machine:

```
$ go build whispers.go 
$ time ./whispers 
100001

real    0m0.952s
```

## "Slow" implementation

The code above is a completely honest reimplementation of the original Go version. But one of the reasons why it so fast, is that OCaml and Lwt is very clever, and although it creates `100_000` threads and `100_001` channels, no threads are ever got yielded to a background, since every time the `whisper` is called the channel already contains data, so the thread is in a ready state. As a result, this is just an efficient loop, that creates threads and channels. It can create a million threads in 50 ms.

So this is an idiomatic and correct way of doing things. But lets for the sake of true comparison mimick Go behavior. The following implementation will first eagerly create in the heap 100_001 channels, and 100_000 threads, waiting to transfer data from left to right channel. And only afterward it will put a value into the leftmost channel to provoke a chain of reaction. This would basically mimick what is happening in Go underneath the hood.

```
let whispers n =
  let rec loop i p =
    if i < n then
      let p' = Lwt_mvar.create_empty () in
      let _t =
        Lwt_mvar.take p >>= fun x ->
        Lwt_mvar.put p' (x+1) in
      loop (i+1) p'
    else Lwt_mvar.take p in
  let p0 = Lwt_mvar.create_empty () in
  let t = loop 1 p0 in
  Lwt_mvar.put p0 1 >>= fun () -> t

$ time ./lev.native
100001
real    0m0.111s
```

So it is slightly slower, in fact it is 20 times slower than the previous implementation (I've used 1 million of threads to compare them), but it is still 10 times faster than the Go.

Comment: I'm afraid your lwt implementation is single threaded, or at least doesn't spawn all the whisperer threads before sending the first message.

Comment: well it depends on what you call a thread. It will create 100_000 threads, but it will not put any thread in the background (schedule it), since Lwt is clever and will notice, that every thread is ready. So according to the rules it will create 100_000 threads and 100_001 channels, but at this microbenchmark we just measure the allocation time. That's why it is fast. Btw, just for the sake of interest I've created a slow implementation that has an array of channels, connected with threads. And it was still very fast, slightly slowe than your implementation.

Comment: I believe the *point* of the exercise is to build up 100_000 threads that all wait for a message. Your implementation is more similar to this Go implementation which runs in ~200 ms on my machine http://play.golang.org/p/cbsD06hrRx

Comment: @ReyCharles, I've updated with a slow implementation, just for the sake of fair comparison with Go. But we all understand that this is just to mimick the behavior of Go scheduler.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the linked post it seems you might want to use lwt which is a "cooperative threads library for OCaml". The result would look something like this:

```
let whisper left right =
  let%lwt n = Lwt_mvar.take right in
  Lwt_mvar.put left (n+1)

let main () =
  let n = 100_000 in
  let%lwt () = Lwt_io.printf "With %d mvars!\n" n in
  let leftmost = Lwt_mvar.create_empty () in
  let rec setup_whispers left i =
    if  i >= n
    then left
    else let right = Lwt_mvar.create_empty () in
      let () = Lwt.async (fun () -> whisper left right) in
      setup_whispers right (i+1) in
  let rightmost = setup_whispers leftmost 0 in
  let%lwt () = Lwt_mvar.put rightmost 1 in
  let%lwt res = Lwt_mvar.take leftmost in
  Lwt_io.printf "%d\n" res

let () = Lwt_main.run (main ())
```

And then compiling and running it

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -pkg lwt,lwt.ppx,lwt.unix whisper.native
$ time ./whisper.native
With 100000 mvars!
100001

real    0m0.169s
user    0m0.156s
sys 0m0.008s
```